# How to show the ViewController's title while using Tab Bar?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I'm trying develop a simple internet radio app for iOS in Swift with the storyboard editor.
I'm new to the iOS-App-Development, so if use wrong words for my problem, I apologise.

I want to show the title of a view controller while using a Tab Bar for switching between the different ViewControllers.

In the past I tried to find an option for showing the title bar (?) in the attributes inspector and I also tried some code for setting the title programmatically.
In storyboard mode it seems to work, but when I run the app, the bar is hidden.

I searched a long time for a solution, but actually I don't get it to work...

Comment: You mean, show a title in the Navigation Bar? (The one at the top)

Comment: Yes, exactly my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Embed the ViewController in a UINavigationController

You can either do that via Storyboard

- Select The controller in the Storyboard
- Select -> Editor (top menu bar)
- Select Embed In -> UINavigationController

Or if you are doing this programmatically you can

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
```

where viewController is your current visible controller.

Comment: Just as complement. It should be also necessary to drag a navigation item to the view controller.